# How to get two values from the two different tables in the same SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have two tables

- Questions

  - Id_question
  - question
- Answers

  - Id_question
  - Id_answers
  - answer

If i use this query,

```
select q.question, a.answer from Question q, Answers a where q.Id_question= a.Id_question
```

i get the question and asociated answers but i repeat questions, for example

question

```
First question?
  Yes
First question?
 No
Second question?
Probably
Second question?
 Yei
```

It´s posbile to get first question and asociated answers and then get the second question and asociated answers without repeat question?

Comment: yes, post your table sample data

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server?  You have both tagged...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not quite clear what you are looking for in the output, but you could try something like this:

```
select q.question, group_concat(a.answer)
from Question q, Answers a 
where q.Id_question= a.Id_question
group by q.question
```

the `group_concat` function will give you a comma-separated list. The output should look like:

```
First question?  | Yes, No
Second question? | Probably, Yei
```

Comment: Note that group_concat is for MySQL only, not SQL Server (OP has both engines tagged)

Comment: Yes, this is the solution :) i have an php aplication and i use two query to get answers, draw the question in radio in loops, this query its more easy